# How to make a jQuery event only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on "DELETE", the function `deleting()` is called. How can I prepend only once, even if I click on DELETE many times? I want it to happen just the first time I click.

```js
function deleting() {
  $(".checking").prepend("<input type='checkbox' name='idcheckbox'>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:deleting()">DELETE</a>
<div class="checking"></div>
```

Comment: The code you posted seems incomplete; where's the `.checking` element? In any case, you might find jQuery's [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) and/or [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) helpful.

Comment: `<td class="checking">${name()}</td>`

Comment: If it's possible, you could disable the button within the function after it has run once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [jQuery one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) in order to: Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.

You may attach the event dynamically and not inline:

```
    $(function () {
        $('a').one('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".checking").prepend("<input type='checkbox' name='idcheckbox'>");
        })
    });
```

And you html could be  like:

```
<form>
 <a href="">DELETE</a>
</form>
```

Comment: I wrote your code, the problem is that if I click another time the checkboxes disappear

Comment: Sorry, I wrote only an example about the usage of "one". This will be executed only one time and so the body of the handler is executed only one time.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use jQuery again, you could create a global "flag" variable, like this:

```
   var flag = false;
   function deleting() {
      if(flag)
         return false;

      $(".checking").prepend("<input type='checkbox' name='idcheckbox'>");
      flag = true;
      return true;
  }
```

But it is not recommended, because you will always have not necessary listener.